# MaskedEditExtender is not working from 2nd line in gridview in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, maskedinput

I have a gridview on my page, there is three columns, one is for quantity, i need to use MaskEditExtender with simple TextBox, but it is working only on first row, from second row the textbox is appearing without mask.

here is my code :

```
<Columns>                        
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qty">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuan" runat="server" ValidationGroup="MKE" MaxLength="5" 
              style="text-align:right" width="100px" Text='<%# BIND("QUAN") %>' />
        <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="txtQuan_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server"
            Enabled="True" Mask="99999" TargetControlID="txtQuan" />

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that When Gridview Render row each Row contain textbox with deffferent autogenerated id and you are given a fixed name in TargetControlID Property in MaskEditExtender . so you need to use RowDataBound Event to Put MaskEditExtender in each textbox....

Comment: will you please provide me sample of this

Comment: txt.ClientID returns same value for each row, it is not working.

Comment: then this property in text box ClientIDMode="AutoID"

Answer (score 0):

```
using AjaxControlToolkit;                                                              protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtQuan");
            MaskedEditExtender mxt = (MaskedEditExtender)e.Row.FindControl("MaskedEditExtender1");
            mxt.TargetControlID = txt.ID;
        }
    }
```

Comment: txt.ClientID returns same value for each row, it is not working.

Comment: then add this property in textbox  : ClientIDMode="AutoID"

Comment: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   AjaxControlToolkit.MaskedEditExtender.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74......

Comment: Please Replace mxt.TargetControlID = txt.ClientID; this With mxt.TargetControlID = txt.ID;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32214/discussion-between-haider-ali-wajihi-and-raghubar)